# How to create a functioning small thumbnail with small play button with Spotify Apps API?

Tags: api, spotify

somewhat of a javascript novice here.

I'm trying to create this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxsm3.png from the [Spotify UI Guidelines](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/guidelines/03_ui-guidelines.html).
Basically a 64x64 album cover with an appropriate sized play button.

This is what I have so far:

```
function DataSource(playlist) {
this.count = function() {
    return playlist.length;
}

// make node with cover, trackname, artistname
this.makeNode = function(track_num) {
    var t = playlist.data.getTrack(track_num);
    // console.log(t);

    var li = new dom.Element('li');

    //generate cover image with play/pause button
    var track = m.Track.fromURI(t.uri, function(a) {
        var trackPlayer = new v.Player();
        trackPlayer.track;
        trackPlayer.context = a;
        dom.inject(trackPlayer.node, li, 'top')
    });

    //track name
    var trackName = new dom.Element('p', {
        className: 'track',
        text: t.name
    });

    //artist name
    var artistName = new dom.Element('p', {
        className: 'artist',
        text: t.artists[0].name
    });

    dom.adopt(li, trackName, artistName);
return li;
 }
}
```

This datasource function feeds into a pager function later in the code. This code generates image, artist name and track name just fine except I can't seem to get the image to be 64x64 without overriding with my own css. I'm sure there is a way to set this in javascript since the core Spotify CSS files include a class for it however I'm at a loss at how to do it.

Also the play button renders but gives an error in the console that the track has no method 'get' when I click on it. How am I suppose to know it needs a get? Is there some way I can see this player function so I know what I'm doing wrong with it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm sure it'll help droves of people too as there is no documentation anywhere I can find on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code here: https://github.com/ptrwtts/kitchensink/blob/master/js/player.js
The kitchensink app displays a lot of the Spotify Apps API functionality

For the playback button, I know that it doesn't seem to actually work for single tracks used as the context. It really only works if you use either an Artist, Album, or Playlist context. Not sure why that is.